# How to separate a char from an int in an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an array list that contains a number for someone's score in a race and next to it is an F or M for gender
for example, "34 F" or "23 M"
I need to find the minimum female and the minimum male value, but I don't know how to separate the int and the char in an array list

Comment: `int score = Integer.parseInt(numString.split("\\s+")[0]);` should do it.

Comment: Will there always be a space in the string that you're processing?  Or could it be (for example) `"26M"`?

Comment: Can you give us an example of this array? Is it something like this  {"34 F", "23 M"} or something different?

Answer (score 1):

The `Scanner` class is particularly good at this.  It has all the splitting and parsing functionality built in.  The methods you want are `nextInt()` and `next()`, for getting the tokens and converting them as necessary.  By default, any kind of white space is used as the delimiter, but you can change the `Scanner` to use different delimiters.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(myString);    
int age = scanner.nextInt();
String gender = scanner.next();
```

Suppose `myString` is `"24 M"`.  Then this code will set `age` and `gender` to `24` and `"M"` respectively.  No need for `split` or `parseInt`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't attach your code?...

```java
String[] result = "34 F".split("\\s+");
Integer score = Integer.parseInt(result[0]);
String gender = result[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate over the list then simply split each of the strings with a space delimiter. 
for example:

```
import java.util.*;
public class GFG { 
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
        String person = "35 F";
        String[] arrOfStr = person.split(" ",2); 
        Integer age= Integer.parseInt(arrOfStr[0]);
        String sex=arrOfStr[1];

        System.out.println(age+" "+sex);

    } 
}
```